# Command \* already defined

Tags: macros, amsmath

I have included the package *amsmath* as required to defined a new theorem/corollary (without number), but I keep having the following error:

> ! LaTeX Error: Command \* already
>   defined.

Now, these are the packages I am including, if that can help:

```
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem*{corollary}{Corollary}
```

And then I am tring to use the new command with:

```
\begin{corollary}
...
\end{corollary}
```

Comment: You need `\usepackage{amsthm}` in order to use `\newtheorem*`

Comment: You do need `amsmath` if you're writing a mathematical document. It's just not sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you need is `amsthm` (besides the recommended `amsmath`).

Add `\usepackage{amsthm}` and all will go flawlessly.